# Error in Capistrano 3 when building task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, deployment, capistrano, digital-ocean

> **I am trying to deploy a crm application to digital ocean with Capistrano 3 and sunzi. (FWI Im a novice in rails )
>   My tasks templates are from this link: **https://github.com/TalkingQuickly/capistrano-3-rails-template**
>    I've tried lots of
>   stuff to fix the error below, : I've changed the file extension, I've added code but nothings helping.. Anyone got any Ideas?**

```
** Invoke production (first_time)
** Execute production
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
cap aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'deploy:setup_config' (see --tasks)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:62:in `[]'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:353:in `[]'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/dsl/task_enhancements.rb:7:in `before'
config/deploy.rb:81:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:209:in `in_namespace'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb:147:in `namespace'
config/deploy.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/setup.rb:14:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/setup.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/tcrm/Capfile:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/application.rb:15:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/cap:23:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => production
```

**This is my capfile:**

```
#  https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv
#   https://github.com/capistrano/chruby
#   https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails
#
#require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
# require 'capistrano/chruby'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'

# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('/tcrm/lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/**/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
Rake::Task[:production].invoke
```

This is My Deploy.rb file

```
set :application, 'tcrm'
set :deploy_user, 'deployer'
set :assets_roles, [:app]
# setup repo details
set :scm, :git
set :repo_url, 'https://github.com/mic50771/tcrm.git'

# setup rbenv.
set :rbenv_type, :system
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.1.2'
set :rbenv_prefix, "RBENV_ROOT=#{fetch(:rbenv_path)} RBENV_VERSION=#{fetch(:rbenv_ruby)} #{fetch(:rbenv_path)}/bin/rbenv exec"
set :rbenv_map_bins, %w{rake gem bundle ruby rails}

# how many old releases do we want to keep, not much
set :keep_releases, 5

# files we want symlinking to specific entries in shared
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/secrets.yml}

# dirs we want symlinking to shared
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

# what specs should be run before deployment is allowed to
# continue, see lib/capistrano/tasks/run_tests.cap
#set :tests, []

# which config files should be copied by deploy:setup_config
# see documentation in lib/capistrano/tasks/setup_config.cap
# for details of operations
set(:config_files, %w(
  nginx.conf
  database.example.yml
  secret.sample.yml
  log_rotation
  unicorn.rb
  unicorn_init.sh
))

# which config files should be made executable after copying
# by deploy:setup_config
set(:executable_config_files, %w(
  unicorn_init.sh
))


# files which need to be symlinked to other parts of the
# filesystem. For example nginx virtualhosts, log rotation
# init scripts etc. The full_app_name variable isn't
# available at this point so we use a custom template {{}}
# tag and then add it at run time.
set(:symlinks, [
  {
    source: "nginx.conf",
    link: "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/{{full_app_name}}"
  },
  {
    source: "unicorn_init.sh",
    link: "/etc/init.d/unicorn_{{full_app_name}}"
  },
  {
    source: "log_rotation",
   link: "/etc/logrotate.d/{{full_app_name}}"
  }
])

# this:
# http://www.capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/flow/
# is worth reading for a quick overview of what tasks are called
# and when for `cap stage deploy`

namespace :deploy do
  # make sure we're deploying what we think we're deploying
  before :deploy, "deploy:check_revision"
  # only allow a deploy with passing tests to deployed
  #before :deploy, "deploy:run_tests"
  # compile assets locally then rsync
  after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'

  # remove the default nginx configuration as it will tend
  # to conflict with our configs.
  before 'deploy:setup_config', 'nginx:remove_default_vhost'

  # reload nginx to it will pick up any modified vhosts from
  # setup_config
  after 'deploy:setup_config', 'nginx:reload'

  # Restart monit so it will pick up any monit configurations
  # we've added
 # after 'deploy:setup_config', 'monit:restart'

  # As of Capistrano 3.1, the `deploy:restart` task is not called
  # automatically.
  after 'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:restart'
end
```

**UPDATE:**
I've updated my gems to 3.10 (they were 3.4.0 before) and I received a different error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/capistrano-3.1.0/lib/capistrano/i18n.rb:4: warning: duplicated key at line 6 ignored: :starting
** Invoke production (first_time)
** Execute production
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
cap aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'deploy:setup_config' (see --tasks)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:62:in `[]'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:353:in `[]'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/capistrano-3.1.0/lib/capistrano/dsl/task_enhancements.rb:5:in `before'
config/deploy.rb:81:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:209:in `in_namespace'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb:147:in `namespace'
config/deploy.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/capistrano-3.1.0/lib/capistrano/setup.rb:14:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/capistrano-3.1.0/lib/capistrano/setup.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/tcrm/Capfile:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/capistrano-3.1.0/lib/capistrano/application.rb:24:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/capistrano-3.1.0/lib/capistrano/application.rb:15:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/capistrano-3.1.0/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/cap:23:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => production
```

**UPDATE 2:**
The cap production deploy went through though when I visit my Ip the nginx default page is still there?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you provided says that *capistrano gem version should be 3.1 series but you are using capistrano 3.4.0.*
In terminal run: *bundle clean --force*

Then in Gemfile paste the lines provided in the link you gave:

```
gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.1.0'

# rails specific capistrano funcitons
gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1.0'

# integrate bundler with capistrano
gem 'capistrano-bundler'

# if you are using RBENV
gem 'capistrano-rbenv', "~> 2.0" 

# Use Unicorn as our app server
gem 'unicorn'
```

Then run *bundle install*

If error still persists then check my link explaining **Deploying Ruby on Rails with Puma and Capistrano to Digital Ocean** the complete guide:

http://sulmanbaig.com/blog/deploy-on-digitalocean-rails-puma-nginx

**For Your Second edit question the answer is:**

In Capfile put these lines:

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/nginx'
```

And in the end remove other two line and add following line:

```
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

Actually you are callimg tasks of deploy and nginx but they are not require in Capfile.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but now Im getting a different error:

Comment: If you solved the question then make my answer the correct answer so that this question can be closed. If you want to discuss the other error feel free to ask.

Comment: I have also edited my answer according to your new question

Comment: LoadError: cannot load such file -- capistrano/nginx

Comment: where should nginx.conf be located?

Comment: The details for nginx, unicorn and capistrano are here so you should use caopistrano ngix gem as well https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-unicorn-nginx https://github.com/platanus/capistrano3-nginx

Comment: the cap deploy when through but when i visit the ip i still get stuck with the nginx default page

Comment: Check the last section of the link https://sulmanbaig.com/blogs/deploy-on-digitalocean-rails-puma-nginx-part-3 to direct nginx to the app and restarting nginx...

Comment: Hey thanks youve basically have solved it but, how do I make changes to my app and than upload them to my server?

Comment: Again read yhe last link in the end I have explained that as well... In short push repo then call cap production deploy

Comment: What is problem coming?

Comment: I've got a site with users and Ive added a few users through the app and then i pushed to git typed cap deploy an when I visited the IP it didn't recognize the users..

Comment: What you means like rake db:seed??? and command is cap production deploy not cap deploy

Comment: Then you have two options first explained here: http://monksealsoftware.com/run-rake-tasks-on-the-server-with-capistrano-3-and-rbenv/ Second is you put a gem gem 'capistrano-rails-console', '~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.2' then in Capfile enter require 'capistrano/rails/console' and then after push do cap production deploy and then cap production rails:console and in console enter the users by doing User.create!

Comment: really youre a great person

Comment: I am glad that I could help... tc